# Android CatLog Application Crash

Tags: java, android, apk

My application after build is crashing when i run it. I have done a catlog but can't seem to pinpoint the error. Could some please help me decode the catlog and what it means not sure what dlopen is but seems it failed.. The device is a htc one m7

```
09-11 09:26:02.530 E/BitmapFactory(954): Unable to decode stream: FileNotFoundException
09-11 
09:26:05.152 E/ActionBarUtil(954): contextandroid.app.Application@41a98748is not      ContextThemeWrapper 

09-11 09:26:14.262 E/dalvikvm(6722): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.mycompany.Chainsaw6-1/libEONViewer.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN2v811HandleScopeC1EPNS_7IsolateE" referenced by "libEONViewer.so"...

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/ActivityManager(760): App crashed! Process: com.mycompany.Chainsaw6
09-11 
09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 
09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722): Process: com.mycompany.Chainsaw6, PID: 6722
09-11 
09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN2v811HandleScopeC1EPNS_7IsolateE" referenced by "libEONViewer.so"...

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java)
09-11 
09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at com.eonreality.android.eonviewer.DummyActivity.onCreate(DummyActivity.java:11)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)

09-11 09:26:14.272 E/AndroidRuntime(6722):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-11 09:26:17.486 E/BitmapFactory(954): Unable to decode stream: FileNotFoundException

09-11 09:26:19.218 E/ActionBarUtil(954): contextandroid.app.Application@41a98748is not ContextThemeWrapper 
09-11 09:26:32.542 E/BitmapFactory(954): Unable to decode stream: FileNotFoundException

09-11 09:26:47.498 E/BitmapFactory(954): Unable to decode stream: FileNotFoundException

09-11 09:27:02.494 E/BitmapFactory(954): Unable to decode stream: FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: Code needed for `DummyActivity` and indicate line `at com.eonreality.android.eonviewer.DummyActivity.onCreate(DummyActivity.java:11)`

Comment: Its not able to find a file that is referred by the libEONViewer.so